# Setting Buttons frame(only x & y position) from array of CGPoints

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

1)I have an array of length 10 and  named 'pointArrar'.This array contain CGPoints on its each index
2)Also I have 10 buttons.
Now I want to set Buttons frame(only x & y position) from array of CGPoints.
I just want to know how to set buttons x and y position from CGPoint contained in array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well its very logical.

Lets say your array is like

```
NSArray * pointArrar = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(5.5, 6.6)],
                     [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(7.7, 8.8)],
                     nil];
```

Then to add to your various buttons you need to simply put all the points into a loop like

```
for(int i=0; i<[pointArrar count] ; i++)
{
    NSValue *val = [pointArrar objectAtIndex:i];
    CGPoint p = [val CGPointValue];
    [Button setCenter:p];
}
```

Here all the points have been added to your button. Hope this works for you :)

Comment: Nice Work!Thanks :)working fine..I have a question that i am animating buttons and place them to one place.i want the recent button on above of all.i used sendSubViewToBack: method to send previous button to back but this is not working...I want your's or other's suggestion on this ..Thanks again

Comment: Instead of that you can either remove the previous buttons or hide them or reduce their alpha so that they are not seen ...

Comment: Sir actually each and every button must be shown but the recent one will be in front of previous one..

Comment: All buttons are not exactly on same place their x position is differ from other once.

Comment: So you are actually saying that all the x coordinates of the buttons are different and they r not on top of each other ?

Comment: See if you are setting different coordinates using different cgpoints then you have to allocate the button too in the for loop.....

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you want to use `NSArray` and it do not store any structures. So you can you `NSValue` to wrap you points and to add them to array. Here is an example..

```
NSArray *points = [NSArray array];
// wrap your point using NSValue
NSValue *pointValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(x,y)];

[points addObject:pointValue];
/// ... add points

// get your point back...
CGPoint point = [[points objectAtIndex:index] CGPointValue];

button.frame = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, button.frame.size.width, button.frame.size.height;
```

Comment: I have a question that i am animating buttons and place them to one place.i want the recent button on above of all.i used sendSubViewToBack: method to send previous button to back but this is not working...I want your's or other's suggestion on this